# Как реализовать placeholder (spinner), во время загрузки Telegram mini app?

Tags: reactjs, telegram-bot, placeholder

Я делаю front на React и не могу найти информацию о том, как реализовать кастомную загрузку приложения. В качестве примера я беру 2 бота (Wallet, Burger King), у них есть свои собственные placeholder (пока приложение загружается и еще не развернулось на всю высоту ,пока не доступен метод expand() ). Я могу реализовать только белый экран и получить свой заполнитель после "инициализации" приложения (пример - бот https://t.me/Nespat_bot )

пример как у меня - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd6hI.jpg
пример как я хочу - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2xCk.jpg

Я попробовал добавить внутрь index.js , но он был отрисован после инициализации приложения. Мне кажется, что этот заполнитель нужно добавить где-то за пределами приложения react, но я не знаю где